# How to make all threads wait only when a certain method is being called

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

**Context**

I'm building a simple logging mechanism. My Logger has a method called `log(String txt)` and this method has to comply to two requirements:

1- Many threads will have access to an object of Logger and so the threads can call the log() method as they wish.

2- Once you create an instance/object of Logger, then a file to store the logs will be created. However over time the logging file will become large and a new one needs to be created.

This is a simple skeleton of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class Logger {

    File loggingFile;
    boolean shouldBeSaved;

    public void log(String msg) {
        if (shouldBeSaved) {
            saveLoggingFile();
        }

        //now write a message to loggingFile.
    }

    public void saveLoggingFile() {
        //close the loggingFile and create a new one.
        //update the shouldBeSaved flag somehow
    }

}
```

**The problem**

Now the problem I'm facing is that sometimes a thread enters the `log()` method and tries to send a message, while another thread at the same time enters the `log()` method and closes the file. At this point I get an exception because the file was closed while the first thread was trying to write the file. Thus I need to synchronise this.

So as I solution I thought about synchronising on the `log()` method like this:

```
public synchronized void log(String msg)
```

However the application that needs to use this logging mechanism has many threads and it needs to log as soon as possible since it's needs to respond very quickly. Thus synchronising like that will make a lot of threads waiting to get the lock. I'm so stuck in finding a better and elegant solution and I hope someone can help. The solution I can imagine to this problem is to make *all* other threads wait *only when* `saveLoggingFile()` is being called. Synchronizing on `saveLoggingFile()` won't solve the issue, since a thread can try to write while at the same time another thread enters and tries to close the file.

I believe this kind of synchronization that I'm looking for has some kind of a pattern or name, so I would be thankful if you can provide the name of the pattern too.

I don't want to use a logging framework but I would like to know how to address such a problem because I could face a similar one but in a different context.

Comment: Use a logging framework. You'll be better of learning how to use a library and logging properly than fumbling around with things in this manner.

Comment: You log method should not call IO operations directly, but instead put messages that expected to be logged in Queue. Asynchroniously saveLoggingFile reads messages from Queue and storing to file (in 1 thread).

Comment: I fully agree with Matt. You should use a loggin framewotk that handles all this stuff for you instead or reinvent the wheel creating a new loggging tool.

Comment: One solution would be to have your `log()` function push a request onto a queue instead of writing directly to the log file, and have a background thread that serves the queue and writes the file.  But what @matt and Ricardo said is more important.  If you aren't doing this as a learning exercise (i.e., if you _need_ a logger), then you should use one that already is available.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Did you try the answer I suggested? That will let you log, w/out the thread trying to log needing to block?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Queue.

```
public class LoggingQueue{
    BlockingQueue<String> messagesToPost = new LinkedBlockingQueue();
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            try{
                String s = messagesToPost.take();
                postMessage(String s);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                //do what you need to.
            }
        }
    }
    private void postMessage(String s){
      //do your blocking io stuff here. It is only run on the logging thread.
    }

    public void log(String s){
         try{
             messagesToPost.put(s);
         }catch(InterruptedException e){
            //this is not a good scene.
         }
    }
}
```

As mentioned below in the comments ArrayBlockingQueue could be used instead of the linked version. This could prevent the Queue from consuming all of your memory. Then things like offer could be used instead of put. Offer doesn't block when the Queue is full. This would be important if somehow errors are being generated too frequently. IO is slow, but not so slow that you should have 100+ error messages enqueue. If that occurs you might want to raise some sort of logging exception.

You could also be smarter about polling the Queue for writing messages, so that if there are a couple of messages you could post them all in one open/write operation.

Each catch block needs to be properly managed because this is logging and it should be one of the last things that fail.

Comment: A `LinkedBlockingQueue` could consume all memory. Perhaps an `ArrayBlockingQueue` should be mentioned as an alternative.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon are you talking about [old issue with memory leak](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=2186685)? Or is there something else about `LinkedBlockingQueue`? Please clarify.

Comment: @Aivean - A `LinkedBlockingQueue` can grow forever and therefore, under heavy load, could cause this method to crash the system. An `ArrayBlockingQueue` has a fixed maximum size and will block if an attempt to exceed this limit is made. Better to block than crash no?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon If the question is only about capacity limit, `LinkedBlockingQueue` [provides this ability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

A common way to realize the logic you mention is to use `CountDownLatch` or `CyclicBarrier`. They are designed mainly for such usage. Simply do at class level

```
private final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

then in waiting thread:

```
public void thisCallFromWaitThread() {
    this.countDownLatch.wait();
}
```

and in the task to be wait for:

```
public void thisDoesStuffToBeWaited() {
    try {
        // do your logic
    } finally {
        this.countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

=====================================================================

I read your question again and I think it's valid to use a queue based solution. Where all your `log()` and `saveLogFile()` are actions submitted to a queue operated by a single thread.

```
private final ExecutorService service = Executors.singleThreadExecutor();

public void log(String info) {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            file.log(info);
        }
    });
}

public void saveLogFile() {
    service.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            file.saveContent(); // or any your file saving logic
        }
    });
}
```

Note that normally when you want to minimize the blocking this is the best way. If you could accept some blocking then a read write lock should be sufficient. Combine that with a double buffer to minimize locking.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer before you could use `CountDownLatch` if you have like an sequential access, but if you just want to lock access every time a thread call this method you simply use `Lock`

```
   private Lock lock=new ReentrantLock();
    ....
 public void log(String msg) {
    lock.lock(); //in this stage the first thread will acquires this lock the others will wait
    {
        .... //do stuff
    }finally{
        lock.unlock(); //release the lock
    }
 }
```

Comment: what you described is the same as `synchronized` in the message signature ... it will slow things down as thread will fight to capture the thread.

Comment: yes, but this is the case with all locks, the goal of locking is to prevent access to the critical section, and locks as stated in javaDoc : Lock implementations provide more extensive locking operations than can be obtained using synchronized methods and statements. They allow more flexible structuring, may have quite different properties, and may support multiple associated Condition objects.

Answer (score 0):

Only lock as long as necessary.

```
volatile File loggingFile;
volatile boolean shouldBeSaved;

private synchronized void checkAndRotateLogFile() {
  if ( shouldBeSaved ) {
    saveLoggingFile();
    loggingFile = newLoggingFile;
  }
}

public void log(String msg) {
  checkAndRotateLogFile();
  // Write message to loggingFile
}
```

Here, as long as there's no need to rotate the log file the synchronization lock is held only briefly for the check `if ( shouldBeSaved ) {`. This is as efficient as it will get. While the file is closed/switched all logging will be suspended until it's finished and a new consistent state (i.e. new open logfile) is obtained.

As others have written, there are numerous ways to handle synchronization in this case, and for performance reasons a queue based approach would be best.